# D3: select only unchecked checkboxes

Tags: d3.js, checkbox

It seems very easy but somehow I can not find anything on the matter neither on `stackoverflow`, nor by googling it. Basically I need to just select all unchecked checkboxes on the page with `d3` and disable them. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select unchecked checkboxes with a css pseudo selector using `d3.selectAll()`, and then set the disabled property with `selection.property("disabled",true);`

```js
var checkboxes = d3.selectAll("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)")
   .property("disabled",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox">
```

Though you should be able to use `.attr("disabled",true)` as well:

```js
var checkboxes = d3.selectAll("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)")
   .attr("disabled",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox">
```